# ¿Cómo puedo quitar las etiquetas xml y dejarlo de manera lineal, c#?

Tags: c#, xml

Ejemplo:

de:

> < cfdi:Emisor Rfc="LEGH870601DM7" Nombre="Una razón rh de cv" RegimenFiscal="605"/>
>   < cfdi:Receptor Rfc="BIO091204LB1" Nombre="Pepe SA DE CV" UsoCFDI="P01"/ >

a:

> cfdi:Emisor rfc="AAA010101AAA" nombre="COMPANIA PENINSULAR DE AUTOS, S.A. DE C.V."& gt; &l t;cfdi:DomicilioFiscal calle="CALLE 86-B AV.ITZAES" noExterior="Num. 644-C x 79-A Y 79-B" colonia="CENTRO" municipio="MERIDA" estado="YUCATAN" pais="MEXICO" codigoPostal="97000" /& gt;& lt;cfdi:RegimenFiscal Regimen="RÉGIMEN DE CONSOLIDACIÓN" /& gt;& lt;/cfdi:Emisor& gt;& lt;cfdi:Receptor rfc="FBE930202QFA" nombre="FINANCIERA BEPENSA S.A. DE C.V. SOFOM ENR"& gt;& lt;cfdi:Domicilio calle="CALLE 56 B  NUM. 452 POR 11 Y 13" colonia="COLONIA ITZIMNA" municipio="MERIDA" estado="YUCATAN" pais="MEXICO" codigoPostal="97100" /& gt;& lt;/cfdi:Receptor

Comment: Quieres eliminar "< y >"?

Comment: no entiendo porque razon lo quieres asi?, lo correcto es acceder a la informacion usando xmlreader o utilizando linq

Comment: Si le quetas los <> como piensas trabjar los datos, porque asi como lo muestras es una ensalada de contenido sin sentido. No seria mejor procesar el xml y extraer los datos que requieres de cada nodo

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer lo que quieres hacer es convertir tu documento XML a un Texto XML que puedas usar dentro de un elemento XML (XML Escape).
Te sugiero dos formas de hacerlo en una sola línea:

> 1. Usando `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()`:

```
public static string XmlString(string text)
{
  return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text);
}
```

Esta tiene un problema y es que no convierte los apostrofes (') por lo que algunas aplicaciones pueden rechazar el resultado.

> 2. Usando `System.Xml.Linq.XElement`:

```
public static string XmlString(string text)
{
  return new XElement("t", text).LastNode.ToString();
}
```

Esta utiliza el procesador de XML de .NET asi qu obtendrás una salida impecable